# Naming a service that encrypts data

Tags: encryption, naming-conventions, naming

There is a service contract to take some class object to serialize and encrypt it `IService`.
What is the best name for the service implementation that does not implement any encryption?

```
IService
TwofishService
AESService     
RC4Service
...
NoEncryptionService???
```

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that matters as much as to have some "convention". NoEncryption sounds good enough.

Comment: I'm looking for a common name if any used in that case.
e.g. NoEncryptionService, PlainService, OpenService, or ...?
I do pay significant attention to naming as otherwise one may end up in complete mess of akward names out of any convention and it will be hard to mantain long term project

Comment: In essence, the naming should be easy to understand without reading some documentation. `PlainService` - no idea why is it "plain", `OpenService` - is it shared or something?, `NoEncryptionService` - hey, probably it won't encrypt anything. That's the basic guide to naming classes :-)

Comment: There should be some name to the message that is not enrypted, e.g. `OpenMessage` in oposition to `AESMessage`, `RC4Message` etc... NotEncryptedMessage is a bit heavy :)